# Proof: Find minimum moves to reach target on an infinite line algorithm

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation

An infinite line is given, where we stand at $0$, and we can move by a distance of $i$ units to left or right in our $i$-th step: we need to find the minimum number of steps needed to reach a particular target.

The algorithm I found is the following one:

```
target = abs(target); 
int sum = 0, step = 0; 
while (sum < target || (sum - target) % 2 != 0) { 
        step++; 
        sum += step; 
    } 
return step;
```

I do not know if the algorithm works mathematically. For example, I do know that for $i=11$ it gives the answer $5$, which is correct, but what is the mathematics behind it?

Comment: I think that you should try it for a few other values, and see whether it gives you any insight. Suggestion: suppose that you end up with "step = 3". Then the numbers you can produce have the form $n = \pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 3$; the smallest is $-6$; the largest is $+6$. Can you produce all numbers in between? OK, what about when "step = 4"?

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @DanielV I beg to disagree. Behind all of this is a nice little problem in combinatorics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given an integer $T$ (=target) and you are looking for the smallest number $n$ such that $\pm 1\pm2\pm\ldots\pm n=T$.

What the algorithm is doing is this: first it assumes $T$ is positive (because the solution is the same for $T$ and $-T$ - that is the purpose of `target = abs(target)`). Then it finds the smallest sum $S_n=1+2+\ldots+n$ that satisfies two conditions:

- $S_n\ge T$
- $S_n$ is of the same parity as $T$.

Then it outputs the value $n$.

**Examples**

Let's set $T=11$. The smallest sum $1+2+\ldots+n$ that is not smaller than $11$ is $1+2+3+4+5=15$. We have obviously "overshot" $11$, but by a suitable change in signs we will get $11$ as, say $1-2+3+4+5=11$.

Let's now set $T=12$. The smallest sum is still $1+2+3+4+5=15$ but it is of the wrong parity. Changing pluses into minuses will preserve the parity, so none of $\pm 1\pm 2\pm 3\pm 4\pm 5$ can be equal $12$. We can go further to $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$ but this sum is also odd. Only $1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28$ is of the correct parity (even). Now, we have "overshot" $12$, but we can now change some of the plus signs into minus, in hope that we can reach the sum of $12$. Indeed, this is possible as $-1+2+3+4+5+6-7=12$.

This is the precise motivation for the algorithm you've shown. First, "overshoot" the target, using a sum $1+2+\ldots+n$ of the *right* parity (the parity of $T$), and then prove that we can change some of the plus signs to minus to get the correct sum.

**Proof**: To prove that this algorithm is correct, one needs to prove that the above two conditions ($S_n\ge T$, $S_n$ of the same parity as $T$) are sufficient and necessary to be able to write $T$ as a sum of the form $\pm 1\pm 2\pm\ldots\pm n$. Necessity is easy to see:

- If $S_n<T$ then, obviously, the biggest sum $1+2+\ldots+n<T$ and it cannot be made any bigger by converting some pluses into minuses.
- If $S_n$ and $T$ are of different parity, then no way of putting pluses and minuses can convert the sum $S_n=1+2+\ldots+n$ into $T$. Namely, every conversion of $+i$ into $-i$ changes the sum by $2i$ - by an even number. Thus all the numbers of the form $\pm 1\pm 2\pm\ldots\pm n$ are of the same parity, and if *one* of them (the $S_n$ itself) is not of $T$'s parity - *none* of them is!

Now, for sufficiency: assume that $S_n=1+2+\ldots+n\ge T$ and is of the same parity as $T$. We need to prove that there is some ordering of $+$ and $-$ signs that convert this sum to *exactly* $T$. In other words, we need something like:

**Lemma**: If $S_n=1+2+\ldots+n$, then every number $T, 0\le T\le S_n$ of the same parity as $S_n$ can be represented in at least one way as a sum $\pm 1\pm 2\pm\ldots\pm n$.

**Proof**: Induction on $n$:

*Trivial edge case*: $n=0$, $S_0=0$ (empty sum). This is true because the only $T$ satisfying those conditions is $T=0$, but in that case $T=S_0$.

*Inductive step*: $n-1\to n$. Let $n\ge 1$ and let $0\le T\le S_n$ of the same parity as $S_n$. Then, either $T-n$ or $n-T$ will be between $0$ and $S_{n-1}$:

- If $T\ge n$, then $0\le T-n\le S_n-n=S_{n-1}$.
- If $0\lt T\le n$, then $0\le n-T\le n-1\le S_{n-1}$.
- The only remaining case is $T=0$, in which case $n-T=n\le S_{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 3$. The cases $n=1,2$ are impossible because $T=0$ is not of the same parity as either $S_1=1$ or $S_2=3$.

Also, $T-n$ and $n-T$ are of the same parity, i.e. both of the same parity as $S_n-n=S_{n-1}$.

Now, we can apply the inductive hypothesis to either $T-n$ or $n-T$, as at least one of them satisfy the required conditions:

- Either $T-n=\pm 1\pm 2\pm \ldots\pm (n-1)$, in which case $T=\pm 1\pm 2\ldots\pm (n-1)+n$
- Or $n-T=\pm 1\pm 2\pm\ldots\pm(n-1)$, in which case $T=\mp 1\mp 2\mp\ldots\mp (n-1)+n$.